# Comparing data between pandas DataFrame and dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I'm trying to make some comparisons between a dictionary and a pandas DataFrame.

The DataFrame looks like this:

```
      A      B     C
0    'a'    'x'    0
1    'b'    'y'    1
2    'c'    'z'    4
```

The dictionary looks like this:

```
{
'a-x': [1],
'b-y': [2],
'c-z': [3]
}
```

The goal is to use the dictionary keys to identify matching rows in the DataFrame (key 'a-x' matches index 0 of column A and column B) and then identify the DataFrame data in column C that is greater than the associated value of the dictionary.

So:

```
key 'a-x' matches index 0 of column A and column B, but value of 0 in C is less than 1 > exclude
key 'b-y' matches index 1 of column A and column B, but value of 1 in C is less than 2 > exclude
key 'c-z' matches index 2 of column A and column B, and value of 4 in C is greater than 3 > include
```

The filtered DataFrame would then only include the entry at index 2 and look like this:

```
      A      B     C
2    'c'    'z'    4
```

In case there are some details that matter this is a sample of my actual data

DataFrame:

```
    Chrom   Loc         WT  Var Change  ConvChange  AO  DP  VAF IntEx    Gene   Upstream    Downstream  Individual  ID
0   chr1    115227854   T   A   T>A     T>A         2   17224   0.0116117   TIII    TIIIa   NaN NaN 1   113.fastq/onlyProbedRegions.vcf
```

Dictionary:

```
rates =
{
    'chr1-115227854-T-A': [0.0032073647185113397]
}
```

Code:

```
return df[(df.Chrom+'-'+str(df.Loc)+'-'+df.WT+'-'+df.Var).map(pd.Series(rates).str[0])<df.VAF]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the `pd.Series` then using `map` create Boolean index

```
d={
'a-x': [1],
'b-y': [2],
'c-z': [3]
}
pd.Series(d)
Out[335]:
a-x    [1]
b-y    [2]
c-z    [3]
dtype: object


df[(df.A+'-'+df.B).map(pd.Series(d).str[0])<df.C]
Out[340]: 
   A  B  C
2  c  z  4
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I cannot seem to get this working. In case there is a nuance that is causing this, I did add actual data in my question and they code I have adapted from your response. But no matter what I try, I always return an empty DataFrame.

Comment: Debug your string concatenation code (look at the output!). `str(df.Loc)` might be the issue, you may want `df.Loc.astype(str)`.